# China M visa in HK for non-HK ID holder

Tags: visas, china, hong-kong

It's a big hassle to apply for multiple-entry China visas at my local consulate.. letters required, multiple visits, long lines and so on (citizen of Canada). A colleague was bitten by a strange requirement- no double entry visas issued for first-time visitors. I don't have that problem- plenty of pages used up with visas.

Some agents in HK offer 12-month multiple-entry business China visas, and imply that they're available with rush next business day service, all for a fairly affordable price (maybe not for you hippietrail). They don't list invitation letters as among the requirements, nor any other kind of sponsorship.

Has anyone used a visa service in HK recently for a multiple-entry 12-month business visa, and if so was the service fast and did it require additional information beyond the completed application form, photos and passport? And if I fill it out for the information from my immediate visit, will that "intention" impact future visits that might be for longer?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forever Bright Trading is a reliable visa agent in HK who I have used in the past.

[They claim](http://www.fbt-chinavisa.com.hk/type.html) to be able to provide M visas with the following information, which doesn't sound too onerous:

> Document(s) required: Documents on the commercial activity issued by a
>   trade partner in China, or trade fair invitation or other invitation
>   letters issued by relevant entity or individual. The invitation letter
>   should contain: a) Information on the applicant (full name, gender,
>   date of birth, etc.) b) Information on the planned visit (purpose of
>   visit, arrival and departure dates, place(s) to be visited, relations
>   between the applicant and the inviting entity or individual, financial
>   source for expenditures) c) Information on the inviting entity or
>   individual (name, contact telephone number, address, official stamp,
>   signature of the legal representative or the inviting individual)

They are very responsive by email. Write to them and ask if they are currently issuing M visas to Canadian passport holders and how long the process takes.

Comment: Very responsive indeed. 3-5 weeks to process and not cheap, but they can do it. Thanks.